# How to make the button clickable when using overlay

Tags: java, android

I want the set Button under the overlay to be able to just click only one button. I try `setClickable` in the overlay layout. Button can't click if not in overlay layout but I want only press Button if I want canclick.
Question: ***I want to know in which way I can do a tutorial that users will press Tutorials use the app***

Open is APP

[image]

When Press Tutorials

[image]

I want Button can Click When Tooltip is appear

[image]

I set the press Button is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.button8) {
           .
           .
            //This is Set Constraintlayout id in isoverlay
            overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            overlay.setClickable(true);
     }
if (v.getId() == R.id.bisoverlay) {

if (c == 0) {
      t1 = new Tooltip.Builder(b1)
         .setText("FragButton")
         .setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
         .show();
         c++;
          }
   .
   .
   .
     }

}
```

I want when tooltip is appear on Button ,Button can Click by overlay is not `GONE`
This XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/moverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--android:clickable="true"-->

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="com.example.test.BlankFragment"
                .../>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                ... />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                ... />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/isOverlay"
            ...

            <Button
               ...
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I use Fragment Button on Event in mainActivity

What Should id do?
(Sorry for English)

Comment: Set button? Which one is it? Make your question easy to understand to readers and never assume they will see your project the way you see it. It's your responsibility to elaborate clearly because we don't know anything about your project.

Comment: I want when overlay appear , Button in not overlay can't Click ,But when tooltip appear is button if not in overlay canclick other button can't click if not (Sorry for english Bad) You can see image , I think easy to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now,I use **FancyShowCaseview** library .It's work! to overlay tutorial user guide,First time, I don't want to use library because want to pratice my android but I didn't have any idea. Thankyou and Sorry for english (I will pratice.)